# Form editing notifications

Tags: wpf, properties, notifications, editing

I'm developing a WPF application that contains a lot of forms (about 20 different forms)
each form is connected to a `ViewModel` class that usually hold a single object that the form is editing its properties.

I need to give a graphical sign to the user if he changed something like in Word when you edited the document and it tells you need to save it.
If the user edited even one property I need to show that sign.

Is there a simple way to accomplish that? I don't want to create an event for every property editor I have (*there are more than 300 of them*).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use INotifyPropertyChanged?!
Since you are using WPF, you can opt for SourceTrigger to Property Changed.
Check here, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15822/Bind-Better-with-INotifyPropertyChanged to know about using INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: i can't since the object i am editing does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I am editing objects that were not created for wpf and does not need to tell my when someone edited them